# Diagonalization: if $P^{-1} A P = \Sigma$, then $P^{-1}\Sigma P = A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

I am learning about diagonalizing a matrix, one of the theorem is that given $P$ some nonsingular matrix, then we can find a $\Sigma$ such that $P^{-1} \Sigma P$ = $A$, where $\Sigma$ is pure diagonal, and $A$ non-diagonal.

But then this would mean that (multiplying $P$ to the other side) $P^{-1} A P$ = $\Sigma$.

But we know that A is not a diagonal matrix, but $\Sigma$ is. Wouldn't the equation above indicate that $A$ is a diagonal matrix as well?

Comment: The conjugate of a diagonal matrix need not be diagonal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Let $A=\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 1\\
1 & 2
\end{pmatrix}$.

and $P=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1\\
1 & -1
\end{pmatrix}$

and $D=\begin{pmatrix}
3 & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$

Then $AP=PD$, i.e. $P^{-1}AP=D$ but $A$ is not diagonal.